# How to replace a function by its body

Tags: coq, beginner

I have this function:

```
Definition bexp x y := bexp_r x y [true].
```

And I have this goal:

```
value (bexp [] y) = 0 ^ value y
```

I want to replace the call to `bexp` with the underlying `bexp_r`.
I tried to use the `simpl` tactic but it did not replace it.

Comment: Please do not start your question with `Coq:`. You can use tags to express your intended topic etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The tactic you are looking for is probably `unfold`. If you write `unfold bexp` it will replace it with its body.

In certain cases, unfolding the definition will unfold too much and if you want more control over it you can prove unfolding lemmas instead and rewrite with them.

Comment: That's exactly what I was searching for, thanks a lot.

Comment: For anyone who stumbled across this thread: "unfolding too much" can be reversed with `fold`. I often define `Ltac refold f := unfold f; fold f` and this often does what you want.